# How to add security to android project other than proguard?

Tags: android, security

I have added proguard to my android application, but when  i do reverse engineering using some third party tools like dex2jar etc. I can able to see source code but just names of variables and methods are changed to a,b and so on.

But I dont want these classes to be visible in this way.I want to make total java classes secure i.e should not be understandable.

can anyone suggest any tool to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 0):

Use [**DexGaurd**](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) similar to Progaurd. It has some advanced encryption in application. [See the difference between those two](http://androidforums.com/threads/is-it-worth-dexguard-someone-is-using-it.955757/).